# Where can I find package of Android Media Player?

Tags: java, android

I need to execute Intent, but I also need to set application directly. I know that I can do it using Intent.setPackage(), and I need to set Android Media Player by default. Please, tell me, how can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> but I also need to set application directly

This is almost never a good idea.

> I need to set Android Media Player by default

There is no "Android Media Player". Different devices will have different built-in "media player" apps.